# CCK Select List widget with "Add another item" functionality?

Tags: 6, entities

With certain field types that are set to unlimited you get an "Add another item" button that lets you create as many fields as you need. If you set a field with a Select List widget to unlimited it instead gives you a select list box that has ctrl click functionality for selecting multiple.

I want to know if there's a way to make a Select List widget that is set to unlimited instead show a regular select list, and an "Add another item" button that creates further select lists.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these modules

- [Select (or other)](http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other)
- [CCK Select Other](http://drupal.org/project/cck_select_other)